# Testing PG Database Constraints with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rspec, constraints

I'm trying to test PG database constraints in a rails 4 using RSpec, and I'm not sure how to set it up.

My thought was to do something like this:

```
before do
  @subscriber = Marketing::Subscriber.new(email: "subscriber@example.com")
end

describe "when email address is already taken" do
  before do
    subscriber_with_same_email = @subscriber.dup
    subscriber_with_same_email.email = @subscriber.email.upcase
    subscriber_with_same_email.save
  end

  it "should raise db error when validation is skipped" do
    expect(@subscriber.save!(validate: false)).to raise_error
  end
end
```

When I run this, it does in generate an error:

```
PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint
```

However, the test still fails.

Is there a proper syntax to get the test to pass?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
it "should raise db error when validation is skipped" do
  expect { @subscriber.save!(validate: false) }.to raise_error
end
```

For more information, check the [more info on rspec-expectations expect-error matchers](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-0/docs/built-in-matchers/raise-error-matcher)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Gotta love the syntax errors.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thank you @user2262149. Your method is more elegant than stubbing `save` and returning either ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique or PG::UniqueViolation.

Answer (score 1):

Slight modification to @strivedi183's answer:

```ruby
it "should raise db error when validation is skipped" do
   expect { @subscriber.save!(validate: false) }.to raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique)
end
```

The justification for being more verbose with the error class is that it protects you from having other possible checks that may raise an error that are not related to specific duplication error you wish to raise.